# Errors of the SMTP server

Tags: php, email

I have my own page (http://www.sthcreative.pl) and I'd like to configure contact form. 
PHP Code:

```
<?php
require('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$mail->SMTPAuth = TRUE;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port     = 465;  
$mail->Username = "contact@sthcreative.pl";
$mail->Password = "xxx";
$mail->Host     = "serwer1553239.home.pl";
$mail->Mailer   = "smtp";
$mail->SetFrom($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddReplyTo($_POST["userEmail"], $_POST["userName"]);
$mail->AddAddress("contact@sthcreative.pl");    
$mail->Subject = "KONTAKT";
$mail->WordWrap   = 80;
$mail->MsgHTML($_POST["content"]);

if(is_array($_FILES)) {
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['attachmentFile']['tmp_name'],$_FILES

['attachmentFile']['name']); 
}

$mail->IsHTML(true);

if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "<p class='error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
} else {
    echo "<p class='success'>Contact Mail Sent.</p>";
}    
?>
```

It doesn't work. I have always errors.

1) SMTP from my hosting - "SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 550 5.1.8 Sender address rejected. The following From address failed"

2) SMTP from gmail - "SMTP -> ERROR: MAIL not accepted from server: 554 5.7.1 Sender address rejected. The following From address failed".

I always write correct mail of sender. My PHP version is 5.4.

Thanks for help.

Comment: What will happen if you don't set the from ?

Comment: for Gmail, try Port = 587

Comment: Could you try to set the SetFrom to an emailadres on your domain (when using your host smtp)? I think relaying is not being allowed for "unknown" addresses, since you could use it to send spam or spoof sending from someone else's mail address.

Comment: The problem was in my hosting. Thanks for your help :)